Powershell List for AD Group Membership Errors
I have a script to pull this list. It completes and provides most of the information I need but I always get a few errors. I think I have figured out what is different about the ones that have errors but I don't understand why exactly. Here is the script-
$exclude = @("DGone",
"DGtwo",
"DGthree"
 )
Get-ADGroup -filter * -SearchBase "OU=DistributionGroups,OU=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=com" -Properties description |
where {$_.name -notin $exclude} |
select Name,description | % { 
  $gname = $_.name
  $gdesc = $_.description
  Get-ADGroupMember $gname | Select @{n="GroupName";e={$gname}},@{n="MemberName";e={$_.name}},@{n="GroupDescription";e={$gdesc}} } |
Export-CSV "C:\folder\DistributionGroupsAndMembers.csv" -NoTypeInformation

There errors are-
Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'somegroup' under: 'DC=DOMAIN,DC=com'.
At line:144 char:3

Get-ADGroupMember $gname | Select @{n="GroupName";e={$gname}},@{n=" ...

+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (somegroup:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember






The ones that error with this script seem to have a Name and sAMAccountName that do not match. Can someone tell me why this would be an issue? Is this even what is most likely causing the error? Is there a way to resolve it other than making the fields match? Thanks

You need to supply an unambiguous identity reference to Get-ADGroupMember - the group's sAMAccountName, distinguished name, or SID will do, as they're all guaranteed to be unique throughout the domain, but the name of an object is not itself guaranteed to be unique. Pass $_.sAMAccountName in place of $gname and it'll work. Alternatively, pipe the group object as input and let Get-ADGroupMember take care of picking an identity reference: $_ |Get-ADGroupMember | ...

Thanks for the direction, that makes sense.
